# DACPAC Deployment in Azure

Tags: sql, deployment, azure-sql-database, project, dacpac

I am trying to deploy my SQL Server project into another database using  **Execute Azure SQL Tak:Dacpactask** in VSTS. But I am getting a error that can't find the user that was in Source Database. I am using Admin credentials to deploy the scripts in target environment, But it shows that the source user is not available in target environment. Since user and logins are database specific, I don't want to make any changes in the users and logins. I want it to remain same. I have attached error in below link.

[Error that I recieved during deployment]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdrsD.jpg. Please let me know how to solve . I have added below Additional SQL Package.exe arguments,
/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=False/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=True /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions

Do we need to provide any delimiter for multiple arguments?

Comment: Is there the code related to that user in your database project? Can you deploy it to Azure SQL Server on your local machine manually? What's the result if you try it with a new simple database project?

Comment: No we don't have any code related to that user, we have only tables SP and functions. Is there any way to find a user is referenced any object in the database?

Comment: @starian, any idea on this?

Comment: What's the detail code of SP and functions? What's the result if you deploy it to Azure SQL manually? What'st the result if you try it with a new simple database project?

Comment: @Starian chen, Just it gets record from table, we don't do any dml operation in it. We have fifteen sp and function all together. I tried to remove all users in sql project but it's not even building in it.

Comment: Can you deploy it to Azure SQL server manually?

Comment: @starian chen, I have imported the db from Azure server and made some changes in SQL Server and deployed in the same DB, It's working,But When I am trying to deploy it in another DB, it's throwing error. I had taken Dev environment copy and trying to move it to Int and QA environment, But it's throwing error, We have different users in each environment.

Comment: Try to right click the database project > Publish to deploy to another DB and check the result.

Comment: Hello @starian Chen, I tried to Publish it in empty DB in my local server(my machine), It published without any issue, But when I tried to publish in empty db in Azure server. I am getting below error.

Comment: Creating <unnamed>...
(85,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 35 User or role 'billingDevLocalUser' does not exist in this database.
(51,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember rolename = N'db_owner', membername = N'billingDevLocalUser';

An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Comment: Do you call `execute sp_addrolemember rolename = N'db_owner', membername = N'billingDevLocalUser'` in the script? What's the result if you deploy a new simple database project to Azure SQL?

Comment: @starian chen, No its failing with above error. I am not calling that system sp,  but that throws error I don't know why its executing that sp. I am using server admin credentials to login to the database.

Comment: Do you mean deploy a simple database project to Azure SQL has the same issue?

Comment: Click Advance button in Publish wizard window, then change some settings and check the result (e.g. exclude Users).

Comment: Starian chen,  Yes in empty database in Azure, I published with excluding users and login only.

Comment: Try to deploy a simple database project and check the result.

Comment: @Starian chen, It's working in local server

Comment: Try to deploy that simple database to Azure SQL Server.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I am deploying the same project in Azure, But it throws error.

Comment: No, try to create a new simple project and deploy it to Azure SQL Server.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I found the issue, It's because while creating schema they are adding one user for Authorization. Like below "**CREATE SCHEMA [billing]
    AUTHORIZATION [billingDevLocalUser];**

Comment: Thank you starian chen for your help.